# MySQL find entries matching multiple pivot rows

Tags: mysql, join

I have a schema with 3 regular tables and 2 link tables like so:

```
tutorial
  id

exam
  id

user
  id

exam_user
  user
  exam

tutorial_user
  user
  tutorial
```

Where the link tables determine which users have attended which exam/tutorial.
Starting with an exam ID, I'm trying to find tutorials whose members have ALL attended the exam.

For example:

```
exam_user
+----+-------+----------+
| id | exam  | user     |
+----+-------+----------+
| 23 |     8 |        1 |
| 24 |     8 |        5 |
| 25 |     8 |        8 |
| 26 |     8 |       11 |
| 27 |     8 |       12 |
+----+-------+----------+

tutorial_user
+----+----------+----------+
| id | tutorial | user     |
+----+----------+-----------
| 56 |        2 |        1 |
| 57 |        2 |        5 |
| 58 |        2 |        8 |
| 59 |        2 |       11 |
+----+----------+----------+
+----+----------+----------+
| id | tutorial | user     |
+----+----------+-----------
| 60 |        3 |        1 |
| 61 |        3 |        5 |
| 62 |        3 |        8 |
| 63 |        3 |       15 |
+----+----------+----------+
```

Tutorial 2 would match because all entries are in exam 8, but tutorial 3 would not because user 11 is not present.

Is there any (relatively) efficient way to achieve the above?

Comment: How do you know which exam "belongs" to which tutorial?

Comment: it's intended as a many to many relationship, but formed by the data. that way any new tutorials or exams are entered with their own data and relations to existing data are formed automatically.

Comment: Aren't we missing the exam_tutorial table?

Comment: This might not be the way to go about things, but I'm trying to derive that dataset. An exam and a tutorial aren't necessarily linked when they are created, but based on the attendance of each I'm hoping to derive those links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about you try something like this:

```
select * from tutorial_user where tutorial not in
(
    select tutorial from
    (
        (
        select ex.exam, ex.user as ex_user, tut.tutorial as tutorial, 
        tut.user as tut_user from exam_user ex
        inner join tutorial_user tut on 
        ex.User = tut.User
        )
        union all
        (
        select null, null, tutorial, user as tut_user from tutorial_user
        )
    ) src
    group by tutorial, tut_user
    having count(tut_user) = 1
)
```

Now the first query should give you a list that looks like this (essentially a combination of exams and tutorials for every user):

```
+----+-------+----------+-------------+---------+
| id | exam  | user     | Tutorial    | User    |
+----+-------+----------+-------------+---------+
| 23 |     8 |        1 | 2           | 1       |
| 23 |     8 |        1 | 3           | 1       |
| 24 |     8 |        5 | 2           | 5       |
| 24 |     8 |        5 | 3           | 5       |
...
```

Next, by doing a union all with the next query, you'll end up with something like this:

```
+-----+-------+----------+-------------+---------+
| id  | exam  | user     | Tutorial    | User    |
+-----+-------+----------+-------------+---------+
| 23  |     8 |        1 | 2           | 1       |
| 23  |     8 |        1 | 3           | 1       |
| 24  |     8 |        5 | 2           | 5       |
| 24  |     8 |        5 | 3           | 5       |
| null| null  | null     | 2           | 1       |
| null| null  | null     | 2           | 5       |
| null| null  | null     | 2           | 8       |
...
```

Basically, what this allows us to do is a group by statement that's going to highlight users in the tutorial table and not in the exam table. The said highlight is going to be with the having() clause. If the count is 1, then you have someone in the tutorial table that's not in the exam table. All you have to do now is select the tutorials from the tutorial table that are NOT part of what you found and you should be good.